# Repeated Output in Widget

Tags: plugins, widgets

I'm encountering an odd issue with a simple custom widget that I made to show contact info in a widget.

For some reason when I add a phone number it's repeated multiple times as you can see here:

[image: Highlighted HTML shows repeated output example.]

I've included the code for the widget below. There's nothing particularly unusual about it:

```
<?php


// Block direct requests
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    die('-1');


add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
   register_widget( 'my_custom_contact_widget' );
}); 

/**
 * Adds my_custom_contact_widget widget.
*/
class my_custom_contact_widget extends WP_Widget {

/**
 * Register widget with WordPress.
 */
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        'my_custom_contact_widget', // Base ID
        __('Contact Info', 'my_custom-theme-support'), // Name
        array( 'description' => __( 'Your business address and email.', 'my_custom-theme-support' ), ) // Args
    );
}

/**
 * Front-end display of widget.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::widget()
 *
 * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
 * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
 */
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    extract( $args );

    $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
    $street = $instance['address_street'];
    $city = $instance['address_city'];
    $state = $instance['address_state'];
    $zip = $instance['address_zip'];
    $email = $instance['email'];
    $email_clean = antispambot($email,1);
    $phone = $instance['phone'];
    $phone_clean = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $phone);

    $address = '<p translate="no" itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                    <span class="address-street" itemprop="streetAddress">%s</span><br>
                    <span class="address-locality" itemprop="addressLocality">%s</span>, <abbr title="California" itemprop="addressRegion">%s</abbr> 
                    <span class="address-zip" itemprop="postalCode">%s</span> 
                </p>';

    $email_link = '<a class="contact-email" href="mailto:%s" itemprop="email">%s</a>';

    $phone_link = '<a class="contact-phone" href="tel:%s" itemprop="telephone">%s</span>';


    echo $before_widget;

    if ( $title ) {
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
    }
    if ( $street ) {
        echo sprintf($address, $street, $city, $state, $zip);
    }

    if ( $email ) {
        echo sprintf($email_link, $email_clean, $email);
    }

    if ( $phone ) {
        echo sprintf($phone_link, $phone_clean, $phone);
    }

    echo $after_widget;

}       


/**
 * Back-end widget form.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::form()
 *
 * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
 */
public function form( $instance ) {

    if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
        $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
    }

    else {
        $title = __( '', 'my_custom-theme-support' );
    }


    if ( isset( $instance[ 'address_street' ] ) ) {
        $address_street = $instance[ 'address_street' ];
    }

    else {
        $address_street = __( '', 'my_custom-theme-support' );
    }

    if ( isset( $instance[ 'address_city' ] ) ) {
        $address_city = $instance[ 'address_city' ];
    }

    else {
        $address_city = __( '', 'my_custom-theme-support' );
    }

    if ( isset( $instance[ 'address_state' ] ) ) {
        $address_state = $instance[ 'address_state' ];
    }

    else {
        $address_state = __( '', 'my_custom-theme-support' );
    }

    if ( isset( $instance[ 'address_zip' ] ) ) {
        $address_zip = $instance[ 'address_zip' ];
    }

    else {
        $address_zip = __( '', 'my_custom-theme-support' );
    }

    if ( isset( $instance[ 'email' ] ) ) {
        $email = $instance[ 'email' ];
    }

    else {
        $email = __( '', 'my_custom-theme-support' );
    }


    if ( isset( $instance[ 'phone' ] ) ) {
        $phone = $instance[ 'phone' ];
    }

    else {
        $phone = __( '', 'my_custom-theme-support' );
    }


    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'address_street' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Street:' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'address_street' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'address_street' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $address_street ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'address_city' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'City:' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'address_city' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'address_city' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $address_city ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'address_state' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'State:' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'address_state' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'address_state' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $address_state ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'address_zip' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Postal Code:' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'address_zip' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'address_zip' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $address_zip ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'email' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Email Address:' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'email' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'email' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $email ); ?>">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'phone' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Phone:' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'phone' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'phone' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $phone ); ?>">
    </p>
    <?php 
}

/**
 * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::update()
 *
 * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
 * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
 *
 * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
 */
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
    $instance['address_street'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['address_street'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['address_street'] ) : '';
    $instance['address_city'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['address_city'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['address_city'] ) : '';
    $instance['address_state'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['address_state'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['address_state'] ) : '';
    $instance['address_zip'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['address_zip'] ) ) ?  sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['address_zip'] ) : '';
    $instance['email'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['email'] ) ) ?  sanitize_email( $new_instance['email'] ) : '';
    $instance['phone'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['phone'] ) ) ?  sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['phone'] ) : '';

     return $instance;
 }

} // class my_custom_contact_widget
```

If anyone has any insights as to what I'm doing wrong. I would appreciate your thoughts.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your widget markup is broken!

Check this line

```
$phone_link = '<a class="contact-phone" href="tel:%s" itemprop="telephone">%s</span>';
```

Opening tag is `<a>` and closing tag is `</span>`. Correct it with

```
$phone_link = '<a class="contact-phone" href="tel:%s" itemprop="telephone">%s</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks for picking up on that, was a pretty silly mistake.